# issue with textfield update in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, state, updates

In state, I have an item like this:

```js
item: {
  id: -1,
  name: "",
  email: "",
  phone: "",
  country: [],
  is_active: true
},
```

Textfield code is below:

```
<div className="col-md-6 col-12">
  <div className="form-group">
    <label><IntlMessages id="DIC_ADMIN_SETTINGS_ACCOUNT_MANAGERS_EMAIL" /></label>
    <label className="text-danger" style={styles.star_style}><sup>{"*"}</sup></label>
    <TextField 
      error={errorInputs.email}
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth
      id={"email"}
      //value={item.email}
      type={"email"}
      onChange={() => this.handleChange("email")}
      onBlur={() => this.handleBlur("email")}
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Handle change event is below:

```js
handleChange = name => event => {
  const {
    item
  } = this.state

  switch (name) {
    case "name": {
      this.setState({
        name: event.target.value
      });
      break;
    }

    case "email": {
      this.setState({
        email: event.target.value
      });
      break;
    }

    case "phone": {
      this.setState({
        phone: event.target.value
      });
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

But unable to update the textfield to read the values. How to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `onChange` and `onBlur` should be like below because they in-turn return a function:

```js
onChange={this.handleChange("email")}
onBlur={this.handleBlur("email")}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two main problems!

For the first one, you should know that `onChange` accepts a callback that the callbacks accept `event` as props. If you need to have the name of each input, you should use [`currying`](https://javascript.info/currying-partials) or [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). In your code, you used `curry`  so you should do this like bellow.

```
<TextField
  onChange={this.handleChange("email")}
  onBlur={this.handleBlur("email")}
/>
```

The second one is about `setState`. I recommend you to read [react documentation about `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). To handle change state, you should consider `item` on `setState`, and it's highly recommended to return a callback to the `setState` instead of an object like bellow.

```
  handleChange = name => event => {
    const {target: { value }} = event;
    switch (name) {
      case "name": {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          item: { ...prevState.item, name: value }
        }));
        break;
       }
       case "email": {
         this.setState(prevState => ({
           item: { ...prevState.item, email: value }
         }));
         break;
      }
      case "phone": {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          item: { ...prevState.item, phone: value }
        }));
        break;
      }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion with fix for your issue:**

Since you are just updating the state and not having any logic in `handleChange`, I would suggest to use `setState` directly as shown below:-

```js
// To avoid typos
const NAME_FIELD_KEY = "name";
const EMAIL_FIELD_KEY = "email";
const PHONE_FIELD_KEY = "phone";

// No need to club all fields for onChange
onChange={(event) => this.setState({ [EMAIL_FIELD_KEY]: event.target.value })}
onBlur={() => this.handleBlur(EMAIL_FIELD_KEY)}

// Suitable for onBlur
handleBlur(fieldName) {
  const { item } = this.state;

  switch (fieldName) {
      case NAME_FIELD_KEY:
        const value = item[NAME_FIELD_KEY];
        // Do validation for name here
        break;
      case EMAIL_FIELD_KEY:
        const value = item[EMAIL_FIELD_KEY];
        // Do validation for email here
        break;
      case PHONE_FIELD_KEY:
        const value = item[PHONE_FIELD_KEY];
        // Do validation for phone here
        break;
  }
}
```